# How to manage several dependent Visual Studio projects for a small team using git?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, dependency-management

We are a small team of developers (<5) mostly working connected to the intranet.

We have have a bunch of C#-projects used in several solutions, some of them depending on 
others, and solutions using these.

A short example:

```
We have projects P, Q, R.
 P depends on Q and R,
 Q depends on R.

There are two solutions using these: A and B.
 A uses P, Q, R,
 B uses Q and R.

The dependencies should also include the versions(commit), e.g.
 P V3.7 requires Q V2.4 and R V1.3
```

So far we have found no easy and safe way to accomplish all of the following:

1. collaborate (i.e. not only personal repositories)
2. put projects/solutions under version control (currently git; this could be switched if really necessary)
3. do this easily without the permanent fear to break stuff if something is not done in the right way (i.e. no `git submodule`)
4. a solution/project should "remember" the version of it's dependent projects somehow.

Right now we include projects a solution depends upon "by source", since it's the most comfortable way to fix a bug this project. But this is not a hard requirement.

We have tried using `git submodule`s, but found it hard to use (especially from within Visual Studio) and collaborate (submodules `origin` may point to wrong repository). Also if one solution includes two projects `A`, `B` which themselves require the same other project `C`, this should be a) the same version of `C` and b) not included twice.

We have also tried to put all projects at "known destinations", e.g. put all projects folders in one "visual studio projects & solutions" folder and reference projects with relative paths. But this only works if you are always want to include the latest version of a project.

I also tried to use a personal NuGet storage but couldn't get it working.

Searching for this topic didn't lead to any results (must have been searching for the wrong keywords) although I'm sure this should be a top for many teams.

I would be thankful if someone could give me a hint how to set up the repositories and/or a set of tools to accomplish this.

Comment: What you want to dos is hard.  You will have to deal with that. Submodules will work, NuGet will work, Branching & Merging will work, each of those can be screwed up

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a second look at git submodules.  It can do everything you've asked for.  You will probably want to spend a few hours getting comfortable with it.  Try setting up some test repositories and experimenting.  Do everything from the command line.  If you're using an integration tool in Visual Studio, it may do things differently or may not be updated with the latest git features.

When you add a submodule to a project, git will associate a tag or branch with that submodule.  So you could do something like this:

Let's say I have 5 git repositories: A, B, P, Q, R.  They all exist independently.

Under A I would do:

```
git submodule add <P>
```

This is a change to A, so I have to commit it with a message:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Added dependency P"
```

Now I have P cloned in a subdirectory of A.  If I want a specific version of P, I would do:

```
cd P
git checkout V3.7
```

Now A would have a change to be committed, i.e. the change to A recording that it needs P at Version 3.7, so I want to commit that change:

```
cd ..
git add .
git commit -m "Use P version 3.7"
```

Now let's say you make some upgrades to P and change the version 3.8.  Back in A, you would repeat the process:

```
cd P
git checkout V3.8
cd ..
git add .
git commit -m "Updated P to V3.8"
```

Anybody else who is also working on A, after pulling from the shared repository, would just need to do:

```
git submodule update
```

Meanwhile, project B, which also may have P as a submodule, could still be on V3.7.

This may be a bit daunting, but don't reject it out of hand because it's hard.  If you get this down, it will be much smoother sailing.

Comment: I think this approach will not work with the repository setup I have in mind. In this setup each user has a private "working" repository on his own notebook and a bare repository where each other developer can pull from. One "blessed" user also has a blessed public repository representing the official version. Each developer pulls from others' public repositories, merges makes changes and pushes to his own public repository. The problem with submodules I figured out so far is, that I'd like to push changes in a submodule to my own public repository and not the blessed repository I pulled from.